# Ler uma String de dados do Serasa

Tags: php, libcurl

Preciso fazer na minha aplicação uma consulta ao serviços do serasa via **Serasa Experian**.

Eu já montei todo o layout e quando faço a requisição direto pelo navegador, tenho o retorno esperado perfeitamente

```
https://mqlinuxext.serasa.com.br/Homologa/consultahttps?p=????????????        B49C      000001050000193JC     FI                   S99SINIAN                               N                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  P002RSPU                                                                                                           I00100R                                                                                                            T999
```

Onde: ???????????? = usuário e senha de acesso.

Agora, alguem tem alguma sugestão de como realizar essa requisição pelo php?
Estou tentando fazer via cURL porem, o retorno é sempre "REQUISICAO CONTEM MENOS QUE 24 BYTES "

Comment: Eles não fornecem um webservice ou documentação sobre o assunto? a url é assim mesmo? `https://mqlinuxext.serasa.com.br/Homologa/consultahttps?p=????????????B49C000001050000193JCFIS99SINIANNP002RSPUI00100RT999`

Comment: A URL é exatamente assim (Apenas substituindo os "?" pelo usuario e senha (Cada um com 6 bytes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aplicando um urlencode apenas no parametro, o erro não ocorre.

Answer (score 0):

tente usar [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php), lembre-se que parar usar uma URL a opção [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) no seu php deve estar ativa.

Abraço

Comment: Da exatamente a mesma coisa.... "REQUISICAO CONTEM MENOS QUE 24 BYTES "

Comment: Fica complicado testar sem autenticação, tente ver o manual, talvez seja algum parâmetro exigido que você não está passando corretamente.